# PDO repeats last bind param

Tags: php, pdo, php-7.2

After moving to PHP 7.2 i stumbled with absolutely weird behaviour of previously worked code.
I have PDO wrapper to insert data. It's code is trivial:

```
public static function Insert($table_name, $data)
{
    if (!self::$connection)
    {
        return false;
    }
    $sql       = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table_name . ' ';
    $data_keys = array_keys($data);
    $sql .= ' (' . implode(',', $data_keys) . ') ' . ' VALUES  (:' . implode(',:', $data_keys) . ') ';
    self::$stmt      = self::$connection->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $val = !empty($value) ? $value : '';
        self::$stmt->bindParam(':' . $key,  $val);
    }
    try
    {
        $result        = self::$stmt->execute();
        self::$last_id = self::$connection->lastInsertId();
    }
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {
        logging($ex->getMessage());
        ob_start();
        self::$stmt->debugDumpParams();
        $dump = ob_get_contents();
        logging($dump);
        ob_end_clean();
        logging(self::showLastError(true));
    }
    return $result;
}
```

In my test I send the simple data:

```
QuickPDO::Insert('history', 
array('dictionaries_version' => '100005333', 'id_db' => 327, 'latest_update' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
```

The prepared statement is:

```
 INSERT INTO history (dictionaries_version,id_db,latest_update) 
VALUES (:dictionaries_version,:id_db,:latest_update)
```

And I got warning:
    SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'id_db' at row 1
Nothing wasn't inserted. Looking into the log:

```
Sent SQL: [141] INSERT INTO history (dictionaries_version,id_db,latest_update) 
VALUES ('2018-06-11 00:32:05','2018-06-11 00:32:05','2018-06-11 00:32:05')
```

We can see, that last parameter only bound to statement!
I checked about ten times, in the loop `$key` and `$val`  assigned properly. This code worked in PHP 5.6, but it doesn't work in PHP 7.2.
How I can fix it?  Or some workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...and [it failed](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#98145) slightly more time ago.

You are binding param by reference and use the same variable `$value` to bound all your params. I'm surprised that it works before. Assume there were some changes related to references/variables between PHP 5.6 and 7.2

As a workaround try to use [bindvalue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) instead